# ¿Por qué al ejecutar la función execlp no sigue con el programa?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando que la función `execlp` me ejecute el mandato `{nl "fichero"}`, el problema es que me lo ejecuta perfectamente pero me sale completamente del programa o acción en la que lo uso.

¿Alguna solución?

Acción en la que lo uso:

```
void MostrarHistorial(char linea[]){
    if((strcmp(linea, "historal2")==0){ 
    execlp("nl","nl","historial",NULL) 
}   

    //historial: lo que tiene que reconocer de caracter para ejecutar el mandato {nl "fichero"}
    //historial2: fichero que quiero mostrar
```

El problema es que después de ejercitar execlp el comando, sale del programa entero y no sigue ejecutando el resto de instrucciones pasadas justo debajo de esa acción.

Comment: La primera línea de su [página de manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) dice: `The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image`. Es decir, tu programa **se reemplaza totalmente** por aquel que llamas. Para esos casos, puedes usar [`system( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) o [`fork( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork).

Comment: hola,con system pasa exactamente lo mismo que cuando uso execlp, con fork no estoy muy seguro de como usarlo,aunque creo que podría ser la solución,si pudieses explicarme mas sobre fork te lo agradecería.

Comment: `system()` no debería comportarse como dices, ya que lo que hace system() es lanzar un nuevo proceso con `fork()`, y dentro de ese nuevo proceso hacer un `execlp()`, para sustiuir el código del proceso nuevo por el del comando que quieres lanzar. Mientras tanto el proceso principal (el que llamó a `system()`) se queda a la espera de que el "hijo" finalice, y cuando esto ocurra reanudará su ejecución por la línea siguiente al `system()`.

Comment: gracias todo resuelto con system(), tenia mal programada otra cosa,un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La función `execlp` no devuelve nada si su ejecución es exitosa. En caso contrario, devuelve el valor -1.